# Removing tabs programatically - Controls created on one thread cannot be parented to a control on a different thread

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a app which uses a for loop and adds tabs. Here is the code.

```
TextBox logtextbox = new TextBox();
                logtextbox.Name = "textBox1_" + string1234[0]; //string.Format("logThread{0}", i);
                logtextbox.Multiline = true;
                logtextbox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(587, 404);
                logtextbox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 6);
                logtextbox.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top);

                string title = string1234[0];
                TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
                myTabPage.Name = string.Format("tabthread{0}", i);  
                myTabPage.Controls.Add(logtextbox);


                TabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);



                botThread = new Thread(() => mainThread(string123, i));
                botThread.IsBackground = true;
                botThread.Name = string.Format("123Thread{0}", i);

                _threads.Add(botThread);
                botThread.Start();
```

This code works fine and adds a tab with a text box and the thread starts. But when i try to end the thread, delete the textbox and remove the tab i get a error.

here is the code i use

```
public void KillThread(int index, int index1, string textname)
         {

            string id = string.Format("taggerThread{0}", index);
            foreach (Thread thread in _threads)
            {
                if (thread.Name == id)
                    thread.Abort();
            }

            string id1 = string.Format("tabthread{0}", index1);

            foreach (TabPage tab in TabControl1.TabPages)
            {

                if (tab.Name == id1)
                {
                    tab.Controls.RemoveByKey(textname);
                    TabControl1.TabPages.RemoveByKey(id1);

                }
            }
```

the program breaks and VS 12 give me this error when debugging.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> ```
> Additional information: Controls created on one thread cannot be parented to a control on a different thread.
> ```

It hightlights this line when i break the program, `TabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);`

What can i do to stop the threads, remove the tabs and all controls. It is a multi thread app so i track it with the id and the strings.

Comment: Is this WinForms?  If so you should include that tag.

Comment: yes it is a windows form application. Thanks for adding it.

Comment: Create the tabs on the UI thread.

Comment: The code in the top snippet **must** run on the UI thread.  It doesn't, it is getting called by a worker thread.  That is not legal, you must use the form's BeginInvoke() method to ensure that the UI thread executes the code.

Comment: May I know how ? I am creating them on runtime because the user may edit the number of tab titles in a list when program is idle. So I want to be able to control it